# bson ObjectId error instance error in Django/mongoengine

Tags: python, django, apache2, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm getting the following error while doing some basic lookups (model.objects.filter()) in a mongoengine defined model (mongoengine.Document) inside Django.

```
id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not <class bson.objectid.ObjectId>

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bson/objectid.py in __validate, line 198
```

Can't see that's is caused by my code in any way. Anyone seen something like this ?

The error message seems odd since the class that's not valid, "bson.objectid.ObjectId", is actually referring to the same class "ObjectId" as listed as valid in the tuple before...

I'm running Django with 1.3.1, mongoengine version 0.8.4 and pymongo version 2.6.2 (mongoengine and pymongo installed with pip).

Comment: Do you have path issues / multiple versions of bson / pymongo installed?  Try using a virtualenv and see if that isolation fixes it.